# Destroy Flash Objects Completely

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

When I destroy my objects that are on the stage. I usually just removeChild(this) and I remove event listeners of the object. is this all I need to do to completely remove the object ??

Answer (score 3):

Yes... sort of.

In AS3 you can not destroy objects. All you can do is remove all references to them, which makes them available for garbage collection. The next time the GC is ran, it will destroy them **if** they are available. It's a pretty big subject, but basically, always remember to remove all references and you will be going in the right direction.

Keep in mind also, that code can still be executed in objects that are available for GC, sort of odd, but it is important to note.

Comment: So I should remove them for the display object. then null them ??

Comment: do everything you need to to remove all references. That includes removing them from the display object. If you want to know in detail how it works then checkout http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html

Comment: Alan posted a great link, check that out. But yes, definitely remove from the display list, and null out any references. Make sure you stop and timers, and remove event listeners too!

Comment: Just to be clear, the universal answer is "remove all references to the object". The side-answer is, if an object is in the display list, its parent keeps references to it, so removing it from the display list is necessary to remove all references to it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you have into the class you used, if it's a loaded class you have to unload it, if you have variable that hold reference to other `DisplayObject` you should null them, etc...

Comment: removing from stage, and setting them to null. would that remove eventlisteners as well

Comment: No you will have to remove event listener

Comment: Though you could create your event listeners with weak references that allow for the object to be garbage collected in the event that the event listener is the last hold on the object.