# AS3 Error #2007 in Child SWF after adding Components to Parent SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've tried many different ways to make this work, but I don't know what's going on. Wish Flash gave more specific error information.

I have a loader SWF that loads and starts another (child) SWF. Everything works perfect until I try adding components to the loader (parent) SWF.
After adding components: When the child SWF is loaded and executed, many display objects fail to load and I receive the following error multiple times:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
    at fl.controls::List/drawList()
    at fl.controls::List/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

**I think this button does not get completely destroyed, and interferes with button code in the child swf.**

I have the following code:

```
btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameLoadCompletion);


function onGameLoadCompletion (event:Event):void {
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT,  onGameLoadCompletion);
    stage.addChild(loader.content);
    stage.removeChild(this);
}

function start (event:MouseEvent):void {
    btnStart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("childSWF.swf"));
}
```

There is a button on stage, that was made by dragging the button component into my library, and then onto stage.

I've also tried doing this with only AS code as follows:

```
import fl.controls.Button;

var btnStart:Button = new Button();
stage.addChild(btnStart);
btnStart.x=670.30;
btnStart.y=486.35;
btnStart.setSize(100,22);
btnStart.label="Continue";
btnStart.visible = true;

btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameLoadCompletion);


function onGameLoadCompletion (event:Event):void {
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT,  onGameLoadCompletion);
    stage.removeChild(btnStart);
    stage.addChild(loader.content);
    stage.removeChild(this);
}

function start (event:MouseEvent):void {
    btnStart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("childSWF.swf"));
}
```

Where there is a button in my library but not on stage.

What could be causing this error? I think maybe it is because the child SWF has buttons in it as well. So, how do I properly delete the button in the parent SWF before the child SWF is loaded so that it doesn't affect the child SWF?

This question is from a stand point of figuring out what is different in the child SWF's environment when there used to be a component on stage before it was loaded. Let's pretend I can't modify the child swf. Why does it work perfectly fine before I add components to the parent swf?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suppose problem not in code you're showing. Firstly, error says problem in function addChildAt() - but you do addChild. Look at exact line number where error occurs. Secondly, try to trace() loader.content - is it OK or not?

Comment: the problem is it doesn't show line numbers where the error occured! :(

What I put in the question is all the information I have. 
I'd rather not mess with the child.swf as it's the change of content in the parent swf that causes this. 

But I'll consider changing the contents of the child.swf if nothing can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You try to remove `this` (the classinstance which holds your loader).
What do you want to remove after loading.
Notice that in AS3 in opposite to AS2 and js, `this` means the class her self - not the event-target.

Comment: removeChild(this) removes the parent's stage content instances so they are deleted when child.swf takes over. there is no problem with this code.

I don't understand what is left over by the parent even after removeChild(this);
I'll try to put removeChild(this); before add loader.content

Comment: nope, just as I suspected, it's too early. but I believe I found something by further scouring the web.

Comment: they took destroyObject out from AS3. Shame...
http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?702902-F8-HOWTO-Removing-destroying-a-v2-component-that-was-created-in-actionscript

I'm trying to null them out, see if that makes a difference.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023058/destroy-flash-objects-completely

Comment: nulling them out did not work. I may have to scrap the components and make my own movie clips then. But How do I make a text input without using a component? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: To be clear: `removeChild(this) ` removes the holder which hold your content!!!! The child-swf don' "takes over". The child swf is an child of the loader( `loader.content`) and the `loader` is a child of `this`. And `this` is a child of `this.stage`. **Do you understand?** What do you want to do? Why do you you want remove something you loaded in?

Comment: yes thanks, but the childswf is the only one left on stage after removeChild(this) removes the stage contents from view.

Doesn't removing the holder remove all references to the content?

I want to remove the components I loaded in, because Whenever I load in components, the child-swf is unable to load itself properly (has missing content, and nothing works)

So I don't understand why flash is acting this way. By removing the components I added, It should return it back to the way it was before I added components no?

Comment: I made an new answer to show the code in pretty way.

Answer (score 0):

OK. You never need to add the loader itself. Only its content. But you have to cast it and write it to a local var to handle it later. After that you can use the `Loader.unloadAndStop()` -method (AFAIK since Flashplayer 11[?]). And everything should be fine.
Try this:

```
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var swfContent:MovieClip;
initButton();

function initButton():void
{
    //you don't need to create your button as a class-var 
    var btnStart:Button = new Button(); 
    btnStart.x = 670.30;
    btnStart.y = 486.35;
    btnStart.setSize(100, 22);
    btnStart.label = "Continue";
    btnStart.visible = true;    
    btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
    addChild(btnStart);
}

function start(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var btnStart:Button = event.target as Button;   
    btnStart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameLoadCompletion);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("childSWF.swf"));
}

function onGameLoadCompletion(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:Loader = event.target as Loader;
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onGameLoadCompletion);
    swfContent = loader.content as MovieClip;
    if (!swfContent)
    {
        trace("no valid SWF found");
        return;
    };
    addChild(swfContent);

    loader.unloadAndStop();
    //do things with your swf, e.g.
    //swfContent.play();   
}
```

I've coded it only hier in the SO-Editor. Maybe there are little typo-mistakes...
I hope, it helps! 
Greetings André

Comment: you are very kind to explain this all to me and write some code too! :)

Comment: Oh man, using swfContent.play() is even worse.

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at childswffla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Now I can't even do anything when the childswf loads.

Comment: this is so wierd. Again the way the chld swf is being executed is affected by the parent calling swf. But this time in a different way!

Thanks so much for your help. But this isn't really needed to me anymore, I just wish I understood how the loader works, and what objects are shared with it from the parent swf.

Comment: Thank you. You're not very patiently ;-)). Flash was build for exectly that, you want to do. What's your code now? Am I right, you NOW seeing the error message the first time? Then you did very well... Now you have to check your extern swf. Notice, that references to `stage` in the extern swf only work, if there is the parent stage available! You have to wait for the ADDED_TO_STAGE-Event, which will be fired from the holding swf, if the extern swf is added to the stage.

Comment: Furhter you can use `play()` only, if your extern swf has a timeline and you want to play the timeline. Otherways you can call every public method of your externswf you've written in it...

Comment: So, I should add on frame 1, an event listener for stage.ADDED_TO_STAGE-event, and tell the swf to go to next frame to start calling the public methods?

Comment: It is not that I am impatient, but that this method of having a button isn't needed anymore, and I am limited on time. I have about 1 month before this project is due.

And everything is fine with this code:

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameLoadCompletion);


function onGameLoadCompletion (event:Event):void {
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT,  onGameLoadCompletion);
    stage.addChild(loader.content);
    stage.removeChild(this);
}

load(new url("child.swf"));

Comment: It only when I have components on stage, that the child swf has problems. Are you saying I am lucky and when there are no components on stage, the extern swf is added to stage faster, and has no errors because ADDED TO STAGE-event happens faster?

Comment: *You're not very patiently ;-))* a joke -sry. Your code is unreadable in comment. A  teahcer of me said: "We have less time - so let's do slowly!" | 1. Make an simple swf with a simple circle or so. Compile it. And load it into your mainswf. - works? | 2. after your answer. You want everything at now. But to understand you could spend a *little* time on basic tests. Believe me: that saves time.

Comment: *"And everything is fine with this code"* - seems it isn't ;-)

Comment: Very nice quote :) Yes, I make simple swfs too when I need to learn things. 
I will try it out if I never need to figure it out! :) 

I did further testing, and the reason I got "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at childswffla::MainTimeline/frame1()"

Was because I did not addChild(loader). I added and now I get the same problem again as in the question: Error# 2007.

Thx for your help anyways :D

Comment: There are more than one problem. The first was the loader. We solved. -Or not. Sorry for my bad understnaing english but did you try it the way with simpe swf or not? the second problem is in your child swf . What happens on frame 1? Is it your swf? Do you have sourcefiles?

Comment: Yes I have, Thanks so much for the help. If you ever make a thread with a computer problem, hardware or Microsoft Windows problem, link me and I'll help you out. :)